# How to align a listing like itemize on the left and some graphics on the right in latex?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have an itemized list like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[\Square] 1
\item[\Square] 2
\item[\Square] 3
\item[\Square] 4
\item[\Square] 5
\item[\Square] 6
\end{itemize}
```

and a graphics like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=5cm]{Passport photo here}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{figure}
```

included in my LaTeX document. They are displayed correctly, but one above the other. I would like to place both in row - side by side. I could not manage this with tabulators.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd use `\includegraphics` instead of `pgfpicture` and `\pgfimage`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two side-by-side minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}[label=\Square]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

1. I used the `enumitem` package and

   ```
   \begin{itemize}[label=\Square]
   ```

   so you don't have to manually adjust the label for each `\item`, but this is, of course, just a suggestion.
2. Since your image must appear in a fixed location, don't use the floating `figure`.
3. Using the optional argument for `minipage` you can control the vertical alignment (possible values: `b`, `t`, `c`); for example, for alignment at the bottom.  both `minipage`s would be like this:

   ```
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   ...
   \end{minipage}
   ```

Comment: So you were able to compile that? Because I get an error: ! LaTeX Error: Command \Square already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

Comment: @Murat Sure; my code compiles without problem. In your case the problem might be a clash between packages providing `\Square`; I used the `bbding` package and you must be loading another one also providing the symbol, so simply use your package and don't load `bbding`. Since you didn't gave us a complete example in your question, I loaded a package providing the `\Square` command; that's one of the reasons why always posting *complete* minimal documents is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Also possible with `tabular`s:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,enumitem,pgf,bbding}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{.4\linewidth}m{.4\linewidth}}
\begin{itemize}[label=\Square]
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \item 4
    \item 5
    \item 6
\end{itemize} 
&
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{pgfpicture}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note here that I used the `m` column type which works in paragraph mode in addition to centering the cell contents vertically w.r.t. the table row. This was required to correctly align the picture with the `itemize` environment vertically.

**Another simple option**

```
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{%
\begin{itemize}[label=\Square]
    \item 1
    \item 2
    \item 3
    \item 4
    \item 5
    \item 6
\end{itemize}}
\parbox{.4\linewidth}{%
\begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgftext{\pgfimage[width=3cm,height=5cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{pgfpicture}}
```

which gives the same result with less effort. Simplicity here comes from the fact that `\parbox`es are vertically aligned by default.